# Como verificar se um array contem um determinado valor em javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

Forma simples de verificar se um array contem um determinado valor.

Answer (score -2):

Para verificar se um array possui um determinado valor em seus elementos podemos usar a função includes().

No exemplo abaixo temos um array chamado `numeros` com alguns elementos. Ao chamar a função `numeros.includes(3)` ela verifica se o array contem o valor `3`. Se encontrar o valor a função retorna true, se não encontrar o valor a função retorna false

```
const numeros = [ 1, 3, 5];
console.log(numeros.includes(3));
// true
```